# Requirements to run Node.js on server

Tags: javascript, node.js

What type of server/service type supports Node.JS applications? 
Is we need to install node/npm on server.

Does it need to be a dedicated server?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It really depends on the needs of your application. As Riv said, it can run on Raspberry PI, Windows, Linux, OSX, etc. Your question is too vague.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need anything special, even a random Raspberry PI with linux can host NodeJS app.

Comment: But we need to start server on local in command prompt(eg:- npm start, node app.js). What we do on live server?

Comment: Assuming your server is configured (I used [this](https://www.toptal.com/raspberry-pi/how-to-turn-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-development-server) tutorial,  when I had my server on raspberry pi I could use normal npm start commands or even better, using node packages suck as [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) or forever.

Answer (score 1):

Since node.js have executable on Linux, Windows and Mac, the hardware will not be limited by what can run node.js, but by what your script need, and the workload you expect.

If you run a basic website with little trafic, a RPi will be enought, if you were to port Facebook or Google to node.js, you would still need complete dataserver.

So the only limit is third party utilities and your own knowledge of the platform you use.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js Application can be hosted on Linux,Windows or any other O.S. And for node.js Application there is basic minimum setup is required. like **Node.js , git bash, npm etc.**

[you can follow this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04)